# class methods not found when extending Django User model

Tags: python, django, inheritance, class-method, django-users

In Django 2.0, python 3.6.5 on Ubuntu:

```
class UserProxy (django.contrib.auth.models.User):

    foo = django.contrib.auth.models.User.normalize_username ('abc') # OK
    bar =                                 normalize_username ('abc') # ERROR

    class Meta:
        proxy = True
```

The `bar=` line throws this exception:

> ```
> NameError: name 'normalize_username' is not defined
> ```

Why isn't this method visible without the explicit namespace?

The same error is thrown from within `UserProxy.objects.create_user`, which expects `self.model.normalize_username` to exist. This occurs during a database migration

```
def commit (apps, schema_editor):
    apps.get_model ('myapp', 'UserProxy').objects.create_user (...)
```

Comment: That is *not* a namespace, that is a class, since it is a *class*method.

Comment: @Tryph you can't use `bar = UserProxy.normalize_username('abc')` in the class definition, it will give a `NameError`. You *could* use `UserProxy.normalize_username('abc')` inside a method, since it will run after the class has been defined.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Are you saying class names are not *part of* a namespace? Does "namespace" have a narrower meaning that's specific to Python?

Comment: Well Python has not something as a namespace. It has modules, and modules can contain classes, functions and other modules. The point is that you need to import something to obtain access.

Comment: I'm using "namespace" in a more language-agnostic sense.

Answer (score 0):

The method originates from `AbstractUser`:

> ```
> class AbstractBaseUser(models.Model):
>
>     @classmethod
>     def normalize_username(cls, username):
>         return unicodedata.normalize('NFKC', force_text(username))
> ```

This is logical, since if every function defined on a class, would simply be accessible by the name, this would result in completely unstable code. Imagine that you create a function `send_email`, and all of a sudden, your colleague also creates such function in a different class, then which function should be used?

Python allows to write functions in a file (hence module) that are not bounded to a certain class, but then you still need to make sure which one you want. A good programming language is *unambiguous*, on the syntax level of course, but also in case a function is called, it should be clear what function is called.

But you can make it more convenient, by importing the class itself. For example:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class UserProxy (User):

    foo = User.normalize_username ('abc') # OK
    bar = User.normalize_username ('abc') # OK

    class Meta:
        proxy = True
```

Comment: This change makes the model compile, but `UserProxy.objects.create_user` still throws `AttributeError: type object 'UserProxy' has no attribute 'normalize_username`

Comment: @spraff: but you should call it with `User.`, not `UserProfile`, since by that time the class is not yet (fully) instantiated.

Comment: This is happening in a migration where the `commit` function has an `apps` first argument. We say `UserProxy=apps.get.model('UserProxy')` and *this `UserProxy`* is being used to call `create_user`, so `import` has nothing to do with it. Now what?

Comment: Did you, or did you not write `foo = User.normalize_username ('abc')` (not `foo = UserProxy.normalize_username ('abc')`)

Comment: I wrote that as *once instance* of the error, and I also wrote that there is another instance of the error. I assumed that whatever fixed one would fix the other, but that turned out to be not so. I appreciate you help. Can you please look at the edited question? Thanks.